# wifi usb adapter working on a computer but not in another one

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers

I have some issues to make a wifi adapter works on a ubuntu computer, while it is working on another one.

I have used the same installation drive, but on a [ASRock QC5000-ITX/PH](http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/QC5000-ITXPH/), the adapter is recognized but the wpa key prompt reappears continuously.

Here some commands which could helps to understand:

```
lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0846:9021 NetGear, Inc. WNA3100M(v1) Wireless-N 300 [Realtek RTL8192CU]

lsmod | grep 8192cu from the not-working computer
8192cu                634880  0

lsmod | grep 8192cu from the working computer
rtl8192cu              69632  0
rtl_usb                20480  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        53248  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                77824  3 rtl_usb,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192cu
mac80211              733184  3 rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu
```

Comment: You installed `8192cu` from some source. It does not work. You need to uninstall it, but you need to know how you installed it.

Comment: I have tried several methods, but even with a system without any previous driver installation, I can not make the wifi working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing "wpa_gui". I had the same repeated ask for a password on my system (Lubuntu 16.04.1)

Wpa_gui is the interface I use to get my adapter to connect to a router using wpa.  You also need to get wpa_supplicant running as a service. You can use "/usr/sbin/service wpa_supplicant restart" to get the service running.  You can also install "linssid" to get clear information about what parameters you should use when creating the network (wpa?, encryption). All of these tools should be run from a terminal window using sudo (e.g. sudo wpa_gui, sudo linssid).

Then, ignore all the other ways to connect the adapter, and all the notifications from other tools.  Do everything from within wpa_gui.  There is a status page in wpa_gui. Good luck.